# Delete the records of Table A where Table B reference does not exist and followed by Table C

Tags: mysql

I am using a huge MySQL database with 3 tables named Student, Tutor and Subject
Student having Tutor_id, Tutor having Subject_id

There are some Tutor_id's in Student which are not present in Tutor table. For this I did the following:

```
DELETE FROM Student WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM Tutor WHERE Tutor.id = Tutor_id)
```

Now there is one more scenario where there are some Subject_id's in Tutor which are not present in Subject table.

Ex: 
Student table:

```
Id  Tutor_id
1      2
2      1
3      3
```

Tutor  table:

```
Id   Subject_id
1      3
2      4  
4      1
```

Subject table:

```
Id    Name
1      Maths
2      Science
4      English
```

The DELETE query I mentioned deletes the 3rd record in Student table as id: 3 does not exist in Tutor but how to delete the record 2 in Student table 
as it belongs to Tutor_id 1 which doesnot have Subject (as Subject with id 3 does not exist).
How can I loop the query with these 3 tables to delete the records ?

Comment: Since the tables have those values they probably don't have foreign keys which means that you can run multiple delete statements in whatever order you want... just delete nonexistent subjects from tutor table then do the same for the student table. You don't need to loop anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delete the student by finding the tutors who dont have valid subjects

So run

```
DELETE FROM Student WHERE Tutor_id IN 
  (SELECT id from Tutor WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT NULL FROM Subject WHERE Subject.id = Subject_id))
```

before your delete from student

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS student;

CREATE TABLE student
(student_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,tutor_id INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO student VALUES
(1,2),
(2,1),
(3,3);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tutor;

CREATE TABLE tutor
(tutor_id INT NOT NULL 
,subject_id INT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(tutor_id,subject_id)
);

INSERT INTO tutor VALUES
(1,3),
(2,4),
(4,1);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS subject;

CREATE TABLE subject
(subject_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,subject VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

INSERT INTO subject VALUES
(1,'Maths'),
(2,'Science'),
(4,'English');

SELECT * 
  FROM student x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN tutor y 
    ON y.tutor_id = x.tutor_id 
  LEFT 
  JOIN subject z 
    ON z.subject_id = y.subject_id
 WHERE z.subject_id IS NULL;
+------------+----------+----------+------------+------------+---------+
| student_id | tutor_id | tutor_id | subject_id | subject_id | subject |
+------------+----------+----------+------------+------------+---------+
|          2 |        1 |        1 |          3 |       NULL | NULL    |
|          3 |        3 |     NULL |       NULL |       NULL | NULL    |
+------------+----------+----------+------------+------------+---------+
```